# Which editor is used here on SO?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, editor

my question is simple: Can anybody tell me which RTE is used on SO, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [WMD markdown editor](https://github.com/derobins/wmd)

Answer (score 2):

check their blog.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/wmd-editor-reverse-engineered/

Answer (score 1):

About the markdown languaged used here (link found in the text editors help!): http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax

Comment: I'm still pretty confused from this markdown language, but i will read and i think i should be ok. Thanks for your answer buddy.

Answer (score 1):

[WMD](http://wmd-editor.com)

Would have posted faster, but their website seems to be down

Comment: Ye i've noticed this too.Thanks buddy